# How do I break a huge WordPress multi-site database up into separate MySQL databases?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

How do I break a huge WordPress multi-site  database up into separate MySQL databases? 
I have 24 WordPress MU-or- multi-site sites, holding over 20K users in total. My Server says I must break them into smaller or separate databases But I am at a loss as to how this is accomplished ? I seem to remember somewhere in the original install a option setting asking if wp should use separate data bases True  or False and it was set to false by default ? but Now I can't seem to find it?

Comment: Did you managed to cut the bases? I'm working locally now on couple sites and I want to hold only one set of core files but different bases to exporting db for each site easily. Please advice.

Answer (score 1):

Use [WordPress › SharDB « WordPress Plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/shardb/) (See also [SharDB for WP 3.1](http://wpmututorials.com/plugins/shardb-for-wp-3-1/)) or [WordPress › HyperDB « WordPress Plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/hyperdb/)

Answer (score 0):

To do this you'll have to have access to phpmyadmin or a friend who is comfortable with mysql. Also, make sure to back up your database before you begin.

If you have a look in the database you'll see that each table has a wp_(blog index number)_tablename. (i.e. wp_1_content...)

In a regular installation all you have is the wp_tablename.

What you want to do is export each set of tables per index (i.e. wp_1_content...) and rename the tables to only include wp_tablename (i.e. wp_content)

Also, don't forget to change the url values in the wp_options table. There may be some other mu specific settings that you'll need to change in the mother site.

Comment: Thanks I will try this, I thank you for your quick answer I am surprised it was so fast! Faith